# ssh X11 forwarding

Tags: ssh

I am trying to connect ssh from my laptop to my raspberri pi 3b locally.

However when I try to connect by:

```
ssh -v user@local-raspberri-IP
```

it gets stuck at X11 forwarding. The output that I get is:

```
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing. 
Write failed: Connection reset by peer
```

When connecting by:

```
ssh -vx user@local-raspberri-IP
```

it gets stuck at:

```
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

I tried to connect using Raspbian as operative system of my raspberry pi and they I changed it for ubuntu Mate, but I get the same problem.

Any thoughts of what could be happening?

Comment: what is your host OS? What is your `ssh` verions?

Comment: when you said "my laptop" what operating system on this laptop are you talking about ? Windows or Linux ? If windows what terminal emulator are you using ? Putty or something else ?

Comment: I am currently trying to connect from windows using MobaXterm to Raspbian, but I tried to connect from another laptop in the local network using ubuntu Lite and I get the same problem.

Comment: I am unsure about the ssh version, where can I check it?